# Take snapshots of flash videos

Tags: javascript, flash

How do I link to snapshots of embedded flash videos instead of the actual flash videos to reduce loading times of a site?

Comment: The answer to pretty much any programming questions starting "Is it possible ..." is yes.  The tricky bit is usually "How do I".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Yes, and in fact</del> this is a method that is often employed. You start with an image with a play button overlay. When it's clicked, the image element is replaced with a flash element that plays the video.

Perhaps something like the following:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("img.thumbnail").click(function (e) {
        $(e.parentNode).addClass("play");
    });
});
</script>

<style>
.toggler .player { display: none; }
.toggler.play .player { display: block }
.toggler.play .thumbnail { display: none }
</style>

<div class="toggler">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="thumbnail.jpg">
    <div class="player">
        <!-- embed your player here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, what is the method for doing that? :)

Comment: You could use ffmpeg to extract a single frame from the source video. I would use jQuery for DOM manipulation. Are you looking for code?

Comment: How do you make the screenshot be an actual frame from the video?
Something mid-video would be great!

Comment: With ffmpeg, you can use the arguments -ss 1 -vframes 1 -r 1 to extract the frame at the first second into the movie.

Comment: You can either generate the thumbnail manually, ahead of time, or by calling ffmpeg at the backend to generate it on demand. See http://github.com/atesgoral/instaflavor for a PHP example.